# dudas despliegue de datos enviados desde controlador Zend y desplegados con función javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, zend

Saludos a la comunidad,

llevo ya algo de tiempo con esto y no me aclaro, se trata de enviar consulta al controlador/controller con una funcion $.ajax({}) que esta dentro de funcion javascript.

Los datos enviados desde el controller, se despliegan con esta funcion javascript, mi idea es desplegar estos datos en la vista haciendo un bucle for, dentro de esta última.

Los datos se pasan, pero algo estoy haciendo mal porque las filas (cuando tengo mas de un registro), me salen una al lado de la otra,en lugar de salir una debajo de la otra..y así sucesivamente.

bueno el código, en el body se carga la funcion

```html
<body onload="verDetalleNegocio()">
```

la funcion verDetalleNegocio(),dentro esta el bucle,for,que creo es lo que falla

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  
   function getLocalidad(){
    
    return '<?=$this->ciudad?>';
   }
   
   function getNegocio(){
    return '<?=$this->negocio?>';
   }
   
   
  
   
   
   function verDetalleNegocio(){
    
    var localidad=getLocalidad();
    var negocio=getNegocio();
    var datos={'loc':localidad,'neg':negocio};
    var datosS=JSON.stringify(datos);
    
    if(localidad!=="" && negocio!==""){
     
     $.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     data:"datos="+datosS,
     dataType:'json',
     cache:false,
     url:"<?=$this->basePath("web/negocios/detallenegocioajax")?>",
     success:function(datos){
      
      var celdas=datos.length;
      var filas=parseInt(celdas/4);
      
      var encabezadoTabla="<tr><td><b>Nombre</b>\n\
      </td><td><b>localidad</b></td>\n\
      <td><b>provincia<b></td>\n\
      <td><b>localizacion</b></td></tr>";
      
     var nuevafila="<tr></tr>";
     var neufila="<tr><td></td></tr>";
   
     $("#tabdat").append(encabezadoTabla);
     
      for(i=0;i<datos.length;i++)
      {       
       $("#tabdat").append(nuevafila);
       var nuevacelda="<td>"+datos[i]+"</td>";
       $("#tabdat").append(nuevacelda);
       
      }
            
     }
    });
     
    }else{
     return null;
    }    
   }
   
   
  </script>
```

la recepcion de las variables en el controller/action
var datos={'loc':localidad,'neg':negocio};

```
public function detalleNegocioAjaxAction(){

    $datos=array();

    if($this->request->isPost()){

        $datosJson= json_decode($_REQUEST["datos"],true);

        $localidad=$datosJson["loc"];
        $negocio=$datosJson["neg"];

        $resDetalle= $this->getNavierasTable()->getDetalleNavieraPorLocalidad($localidad);
        if($resDetalle){



            foreach ($resDetalle as $value) {
                $datos[]=$value->nombre;
                $datos[]=$value->localidad;
                $datos[]=$value->provincia;
                $datos[]=$value->localizacion;
            }               

             $vista=new ViewModel(array("data"=>$datos));
            $vista->setTerminal(true);
            return $vista;

        }

    }

}
```

en la vista detallenegocioajax.phtml, se "sacan" los datos con echo y json_encode()

```
<?php
```

echo json_encode($data);

y por ultimo en la vista negocios.phtml, el resultado ...solo funciona cuando se muestra una sola fila,cuando ya sacamos mas una fila, aparecen una al lado de la otra...que hago mal?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos y muchas gracias por anticipado!!

Answer (score 0):

Saludos no te compliques tanto para rellenar tu table podrias hacerlo asi:
primero definimos el table:

```
<table id="tabdat" border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Localidad</th>
      <th>Provincia</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

bien con esto ya creamos por defecto el encabezado de el table solo nos queda ingresar el cuerpo(tbody) para ello lo hariamos con algo asi:
//data fictisia

```
data = [{'nombre':'Escuela San Jose', 'localidad':'San Jose', 'provincia':'Ibiza'}, {'nombre':'Naviera Pepe', 'localidad':'Ibiza', 'provincia':'Ibiza Sur'}]
console.log(data);
html = "";
for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
 html += "<tr>"
 html += "<td>"+data[i]['nombre']+"</td>";
 html += "<td>"+data[i]['localidad']+"</td>";
 html += "<td>"+data[i]['provincia']+"</td>";
 html += "</tr>";
}
$("#tabdat tbody").append(html);
```

bien ahora a probarlo:

```js
data = [{'nombre':'Escuela San Jose', 'localidad':'San Jose', 'provincia':'Ibiza'}, {'nombre':'Naviera Pepe', 'localidad':'Ibiza', 'provincia':'Ibiza Sur'}]
html = "";
for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
 html += "<tr>"
 html += "<td>"+data[i]['nombre']+"</td>";
 html += "<td>"+data[i]['localidad']+"</td>";
 html += "<td>"+data[i]['provincia']+"</td>";
 html += "</tr>";
}
$("#tabdat tbody").append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabdat" border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Localidad</th>
      <th>Provincia</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Espero te sirva de guia y pruebalo.

Answer (score 0):

muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta,

bueno creo que he seguido con rigor tus indicaciones, y la tabla está mas "ordenada",pero
ahora los datos aparecen como "undefined"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola de nuevo, estuve mirando el controller/action, y he cambiado algunas cosas,
ahora está así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y en la vista, en el bucle, también he modificado algunas cosas,los datos llegan pero me estoy haciendo un lío con el índice del bucle, y las celdas de la tabla..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la vista...me saca los datos desordenados, en esta caso, tiene que mostrar dos filas de MySql, de cuatro columnas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya para completar, os pongo la funcion del modelo, que hace la consulta MySql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias anticipadas a la comunidad...Saludos!